# Cannot install in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++-winrt, visual-studio-2022, visx

I get a notification telling me this is available in Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.0.0 Preview 4.1).  However, it will not install - any advice?

The errorlog shows the following:

```
10/1/2021 8:06:19 AM - A cycle was detected in the dependency graph: 
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.VC
  ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.VC
10/1/2021 8:06:19 AM - Install Error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyGraphConstructionException: A cycle was detected in the dependency graph: 
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.VC
  ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.VC
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.GetProductDependencyGraph(Product product, Boolean overwrite)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.get_GetProductDependencyGraph()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
```

Comment: "*telling me this is available*" What is "this" referring to?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the C++/WinRT VSIX and Visual Studio 2022 Preview 4.1:

- [Unable to update from Preview 1.1 to Preview 2.0. A cycle was detected in the dependency graph: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.VC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-update-from-preview-11-to-preview-20-a-c/1476321) (Microsoft claims to have fixed the issue, though it's still there for everyone trying to update the C++/WinRT VSIX)
- [VS 2022 VSIX support](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/960) (Bug report against the C++/WinRT repo about the update issue; no resolution thus far)

At this time it has not been officially described, what the issue is, which team will need to resolve it or when we can expect to receive an update.